# How to verify "Contains" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

In the below code I have to check whether the textbox contains `@` and `.`. I tried writing the below code which is not working. Anybody please do provide me with the correct syntax.

```
    function emailval(objval) {
        if (obj.value.contains("@") && obj.value.contains(".")) {
            document.getElementById(mid).style.backgroundColor = "#BDD470";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(mid).style.backgroundColor = "#CC0505";
        }
    }

</script>

Enter text (Enter your email):
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeyup="return emailval(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
</form>
```

Comment: -1 The statement "not working" is "a useless statement". Please take time to debug/explain the problem more. I suspect it is because "one can't apply the () operator to the undefined value".

Comment: There is no contains in javascript. You can add your own - this SO thread answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains

Comment: `mid` and `obj` are not defined.

Comment: The function parameter name is `objVal` and you are using `obj` in the function. Change the parameter anem to `obj`.

Comment: `objval` is your parameter, yet you're referencing `obj.val`?

Comment: Duplicate of (most of) these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+string+contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need -

```
if (obj.value.indexOf("@") != -1 && obj.value.indexOf(".") != -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For native string contains use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
 str.indexOf('@') !== -1; // str contains '@' true
```

Answer (score 1):

or the regex way... just because it's there

```
if(obj.value.match(/[.].*[@]|[@].*[.]/))
```